# Does the integral commutes with partial derivative s in this expression?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-derivative

Let $e_i$, $1 \leq i \leq n$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Condider the partial derivative $\partial_i $  in the direction of $e_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Let f be a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

How can we simplify the following expression  $\sum_i \partial_i(\int_0^1 f(tx +y)t^{k-1}dt) $? Does the partial derivative commute  with the integral ?

Comment: Do you know any theorem about interverting derivatives and integrals ?

Comment: @Flewer, I know that in general we can't  interchange integral and derivatives, but I don't know what are tee conditions to do so and what is the name of theorem which tell us when we can interchange them. Since f in this case is very regular I assumed that we can commute them but didn't get a simplification of the formula in the question

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign
In the case your function is indeed smooth, all the hypothesis are verified and you can commute the differential operator and the integral. Note here that the bounds are constant: $a(x)=0$ and $b(x)=1$.